# How to I show the user and last message from database table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making a chatting system. There I need to show the user and the last message between them. 
I want to show like this:

[image]

My database table:

[image]

About the database:
There are two copies of a message. SO, copy_uid means that this message which user copy.

m_id : message id
ua_id : user who receive the message his id
u_id : user who sent the message his id
copy_uid : a message should be two copy one sender and another receiver

Comment: Great. Go for it !

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You can use orderBy in your sql query.

Comment: The details are full

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this table structure:

[image]

#### Answer:

```
SELECT * FROM `message` `m1` 
WHERE m_id IN (
  SELECT MAX(m2.m_id) 
  FROM `message` `m2` WHERE m2.`sender` = 1 OR m2.`receiver` = 1 
  GROUP BY (IF(m2.`sender`= 1, m2.`receiver`, m2.`sender`))) 
ORDER BY time DESC
```

Assume current user id is `1`

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, @ArjunKariyadan Whats that means by  `m1`

Comment: That's table alias - used to give a table, or a column in a table, a temporary name; refer [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) link. In this case you can omit `m1` alias because it's not using elsewhere. But `m2` alias is helpful, though.

Comment: You can use another syntax by using `AS` keyword. For e.g. `message AS m1`

Comment: Greate. It's working. Thanks a lot. But I need to another condition that `copy_uid=1` Where can I give it. Could please send me a code with this condiotion. I am really grateful for you!! Thanks again-

Comment: Try this but i am not sure this is exactly what you want: **SELECT * FROM message m1 
WHERE m_id IN (
  SELECT MAX(m2.m_id) 
  FROM message m2 WHERE m2.sender = 1 OR m2.receiver = 1 
  GROUP BY (IF(m2.sender= 1, m2.receiver, m2.sender))) AND copy_uid=1
ORDER BY time DESC**

Comment: @sultanul You're always welcome. **Happy coding! :)**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157737/discussion-between-arjun-kariyadan-and-sultanul).

Comment: It works i was up-voted to your answer @Arjun

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, simplify your structure message table:

**id**: auto increment
**sender_id**
**recipient_id**
**sent**: bool default 0
**text**

next message for user_id

```
select * from msg order by id desc 
where recipient_id=user_id and sent=0
limit 1
```

store $msgId = msg.id

after sending
update msg set sent = 1 where  id = $msgId